# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, pom.xml

I am linking Struts2 and hibernate with help of struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin.

Unfortunately I get this error . I found that the problem may be on my class-path with hibernate versions.

Here is my `pom.xml`. **It is now edited and works perfectly**:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependencies of hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/StrutsHibernate] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.createAndTestSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:284)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:227)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getNewSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:155)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.util.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:100)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.getHibernateSessionFromFactory(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:379)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:454)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSessionByAnnotation(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:470)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
```

Can someone look at my pom to say what is wrong there?

Comment: It looks like you are explicitly defining hibernate's transitive dependencies in your pom.xml (eg commons-collections, cflib etc). Why are you doing this? Do you realise that by declaring struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin you will also bring in hibernate and all the other transitive dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'NoSuchMethodError' occurrs when a library (ie struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin) was compiled against one version of a dependency (ie hibernate) but it is run against another version.

Run the following command from the command line:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And take a look at the hibernate version that the `struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin` expects.

I'm guessing that you will find that `struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin` expects a certain version of hibernate. But since you explicitely define a version of hibernate in your pom maven uses this version instead. See the nearest definition wins strategy [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

To fix, change the hibernate version in your pom.xml to the version expected by `struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin`.

Comment: Eclipse gives me this dependency tree. Why did `mvn dependency:tree` download some jars?

Comment: The dependency tree maven plugin requires it's own dependencies to execute. Don't worry, these will not be included in your project's artifact.

Comment: I found all dependencies required by `struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin` [here](http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/wiki/7_Dependencies)